# Code analysis in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Does Eclipse have a built-in code analysis tool? I want it to show warnings for code like that:

```
Integer a=hashMap.get("someKey");
//may produce null pointer exception
//copy paste error
if(a==2 && a==2)
{
 //empty body
}
```

Also it will be very useful to se unused resources like classes, files,methods and constants.

Comment: you can always use SonarQube, and implement your own ruleset above the default one

Comment: AFAIK there are standard eclipse warnings for these two. Open "Window/Preferences" and check settings under "Java/Comnpiler/Errors/Warnings". At least in Eclipse Luna, the first one can be found under "Null analysis", the second under "Code Style" (but it only displays a warning if the empty block is undocumented).

Comment: I use Checkstyle and Findbugs. Also Eclemma, when I want an ad-hoc test coverage report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SonarQube, now called [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) depending on what version of Eclipse you are in.

There is also the [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) plugin.

They both work kind of the same. SonarLint in my opinion is better. It has multiple classifications of errors like Critical, Major, Minor an explanation what the problem is and you can hook it up to your Jenkins build (if you use it) to stop a deploy if it finds a Critical error or whatever alert level you want to us.

Finally SonarLint can look at what the server errors are vs your local branch errors allowing you to catch potential issues as you write your code.